# Not able to access my Tomcat web application through IPv6 but works fine with IPv4

Tags: linux, java, ipv6

I have a web application running on Tomcat. I can access it through IPv4 IP but not through IPv6 IP.

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8060

tcp 0 0 :::8060 :::* LISTEN 7216/java
```

The port 8060 listens to IPv6 protocol.

I have tried providing `-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses` as an java opts, and enclosing the IPV6 IP into [] while opening it through IE11, but nothing works. What can I do?

My system proxy Internet connection supports only IPV4.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have an IPv4 available, you won't be able to connect using IPv6 which is a different protocol.   On your server, you may be able to connect to the service on the IPv6 local host address,`::1`.

If you have the `ip` command available, then the command `ip -6 addr` will list other addresses that can be used to connect from systems on the same network segment.

To connect to an application on the same server you may need to specify the host and port in the format `[::1]:8060`.